# Copy the file path to clipboard with batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, clipboard, imacros, clip

I want to run a batch file and take a full path of file if it exist to the clipboard. Later I will use this information for IMacros.

I have already do this :

```
echo D:\workset\MC_DIM\Val_to_Dal.zip | clip
```

But when i try to use this in IMacros, It doesn't work correctly. So I want to copy the path not like String like the directory. Is it possible with batch scripting?

Comment: Have you seen that there is an aditional space at the end of the file name?

Comment: ahh, should it be like this : 
`echo D:\workset\MC_DIM\Val_to_Dal.zip| clip`

Comment: @MCND I check but the problem is not that. Actually the problem is about IMacros. When use `{{!Clipboard}}` command in textfield I can see that my batch script is work fine. But when i click the browse and use `{{!Clipboard}}` then the command added `-` this to the end of the string. So I am trying to take the path like a directory not a string.

Answer (score 0):

How about echo D:\workset\MC_DIM\Val_to_Dal.zip | pbcopy ?

Answer (score 0):

iMacros has a support for clipboard.

http://wiki.imacros.net/!CLIPBOARD

Here are 2 examples.

Copy data from the clipboard to a website:

```
 URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/f1/form.asp
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:TestForm ATTR=NAME:Remarks CONTENT=Clipboard<SP>content<SP>=<SP>{{!CLIPBOARD}}
```

Copy data extracted from a website into the clipboard:

```
 URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/extract2/       
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:bdytxt&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT  
 SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
```

For the rest you can use their forum.

[iMacros Forum](http://forum.iopus.com)